# Browser GET request returning old images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, tomcat

I'm trying to use a GET request to retrieve an image from a server. The image is constantly changing, so I want to grab the image a few times every second (with the intent of displaying the images and imitating video eventually). However, there's something going wrong with the GET request. No matter how rapidly I try to GET the image (tried every 1s, 100ms, etc), it only returns a new image every 5 seconds. It's acting like there's a cached image somewhere and it's only updating the cache every 5 seconds, returning old, duplicate images all other times.

I've done the following to try to isolate the problem:

- Verified that the images on the server side are actually being updated every 100ms or so, meaning the webpage is indeed returning old images for most of its GET requests,
- Turned off the browser cache both through developer options and by running the webpage in incognito mode. This is Chrome by the way.
- Turned off keepalive in the Tomcat server by setting maxKeepAliveRequests = 1 (disabled) in the configuration file.

And yet it is still only actually retrieving new images every 5 seconds.

```
Example Request Headers:
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Connection: keep-alive     <-- Could this be the problem? 
  Pragma: no-cache

Example Response Headers:
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Connection: close
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

My query (executed after a time delay every time image is loaded):

```
document.getElementById("videoDisplay").src = filename + "?random="+(new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: Are you returning the image through your own service? Perhaps a Java servlet?

Comment: Turn off the connection keep alive. Also why don't you create a gif and fetch the gif instead?

Comment: @PatrickD, The filename is a file URL that contains the actual image, so not really a service. It is going through Spring to get there however.

Comment: @idipous, I'll try turning off the keep alive in the browser. I assumed it didn't matter because the server has keep alive disabled, but its definitely worth a try. And why would the gif be different? Not supposed to sound snooty, I just don't know much about when to use what image formats and why.

Comment: I would suggest gif because it is easy to create animated images and no need to fetch many images in rapid succession. Just one gif.

Comment: @idipous, good idea, but the problem with my specific project is that I am constructing the jpeg in realtime from a streaming video. I'm not sure how hard creating a gif from that would be, but either way it would delay the video by about 5 seconds as it gathered the information needed to construct the 5 second gif. We need this to update images on the website in as close to real time as possible, definitely faster than a 5 second delay.

Comment: If it is not realtime live video, try bundling the images sequentially first before previewing. Also check `chrome://cache` in another window to see if it is really getting cached.

Comment: did you check if the request is going to the server every 1 second? Is the server handling or ignoring it?

Comment: check chromes network tab if the images are really getting requested and displayed at the rate you think they are

Comment: The issue is probably to do with the server only allowing a small number of requests per second from a single IP. You should check your server logs and the network activity (dev tools network tab in Chrome is pretty nifty for this).

Comment: keep-alive determines whether the connection has to be re-established with each request or not. It has no effect on caching. I suggest you have keep-alive on as it will improve performance

Comment: Just throwing this idea out there, what if you append a unique id to the url string? I recently had a problem with FF caching my URLs. To resolve this I generated a random number and appended a "&uid=34123" to my url string.

Comment: @Vega, unfortunately, it is realtime live video :(.

Comment: @MarZab, I've been watching the networks tab, they are getting "requested" at least on the browser side, and I can see an image returned (shows up as a thumbnail in the networks tab) for each call. Again, the same image is returned over and over for five seconds before it updates, but each request is definitely returning something.

Comment: @RobJ, good thinking! I'll check when I get access to the server again. If that does turn out to be the problem, I'll let you know so you can write up a question and give you the bounty. Also, good to know about keep alive. I kinda thought it might not have anything to do with it, but I'm desperate :).

Comment: @spots, would that work any differently than adding the query to the end of the filename like I have now?

Comment: can we get some sources from the script making the stream/images?

Comment: @MarZab, unfortunately no as its government property. I have, however, verified the images are all valid jpeg images by viewing them directly(ish) on the server as they are being created. It's definitely a lost in translation error, not an image creation error. Hope that helps!

Comment: @fmodos has a good point. Did you check it?

Comment: Just an idea: what about streaming an animated gif? I found this code by quickly googling: https://github.com/jbochi/gifstreaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html 
Read this entry there..

### **cacheTTL**

Amount of time in milliseconds between cache entries revalidation. If not specified, the default value is 5000 (5 seconds).

May be this is the source of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking:

lets suppose you set the interval to 500 msec.

Your server needs 1 sec to answer the request.

So, while waiting for the first request, the timeout function is issuing an other one on the same object.

This usually will stop the first request.

The second one is still not there, so nothing will change.

And so forth.

After some while this will fall back "in sync" and you get an arbitrary image.

So, what are the response times of your server?

If the server's to slow, it doesn't matter on how fast you update on the same object.

You might have some lock on the image while loading to prevent issuing requests w/o waiting for them to complete?

Comment: Good thinking, but I can see by the network tab in Chrome that the round trip time of each request is much faster than the polling interval, so unfortunately that's not the problem in this case.

Comment: hmm, I'm quite sure that it is a timing issue. Hav you tried to just get one new image after lets say 2 seconds and stop afterwards?

Comment: I don't know how Tomcat is serving images and finally on how you're updating them on the server. Lets assume, youre just overwriting the same file inode, probably tomcat has cached the contents (so does apache in certain configurations on plain files). would mean: you get "fresh" content due to the "pragma: no cache" and "expires" stuff, but it hasn't been grabbed from the disk but from an internal inode cache and though its old?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- Add an `Expires:` header, set it to a few seconds ago
- Use a POST request to get your data. Get it meant to retrieve stuff that might be fetched more than once. POST is my design meant for "this time only"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar once, honestly images are not supposed to be videos. The speed is limited to five seconds so you don't overwork the server and DDOS it (at least that is what I think, not really sure though). You can stream a video with HTML5  tag. You might consider these sites that my good friend Google showed me.
[This is one](http://www.brightcove.com/en/online-video-platform/html5-video-player)
[Try this one too](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/)